# error in opening Ulipad for python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am familiar with R but new to Python. 
To use python, I installed Python 2.7, set environment variables and installed wxPython. And then, after installing Ulipad I opened Ulipad but an  error message showed this:

> The logfile 'C:\program file(x86)\Ulipad\Ulipad.exe.log' could not be opened:[Errno13] Permission denied: 'C:\program file(x86)\Ulipad\Ulipad.exe.log'

Can you help me to open the Ulipad? Or Is there any other good program like Ulipad? 
I am not good at programming but only familiar with R. Python seems to be little different from R in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because under newer Windows OS(Vista, 7, 8) programs do not have write access to "C:\program file(x86)\" for security reasons. Easiest fix for your problem would be to uninstall the current installation and re-install it at a different location e.g. C:\Ulipad. Alternative is to run Ulipad using "Run as an administrator" option but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was:

1. uninstall Ulipad
2. install Ulipad on a different disk, e.g. `D:\Ulipad`